# Macro VBA, trying to combine SumIfs and Left

Tags: vba, excel, function

I am trying to run a `Sumifs` function in VBA with `Left` function inside:

I have:

```
Sub refresh_OEdc_data_files()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wB As Workbook
    Dim SumResult As Double
    Dim OutPutRange As Range
    Set FileSystemObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Fill it with your own adress
    Set FolderObj = FileSystemObj.GetFolder("C:...\")
    Set OutPutRange = Workbooks("Libro4").Sheets("Hoja1").Range("D4")
    For Each fileobj In FolderObj.Files
        Set wB = Workbooks.Open(fileobj.Path)

       For Each fileobj In FolderObj.Files
           Set wB = Workbooks.Open(fileobj.Path)
           'My Problem is here
           SumResult = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(wB.Sheets("Schedule Daily Bank Structure R").Range("A:A"), Left(wB.Sheets("Schedule Daily Bank Structure R").Range("H6:H414").Value, 2), "<1", Left(wB.Sheets("Schedule Daily Bank Structure R").Range("H6:H414").Value, 2), "=>3")

           OutPutRange.Value = SumResult
           Set OutPutRange = OutPutRange.Offset(1, 0)
        wB.Save
    wB.Close

    Next fileobj
End Sub

'SumResult2 = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(wB.Sheets("Schedule Daily Bank Structure R").Range("A:A"), Left(wB.Sheets("Schedule Daily Bank Structure R").Range("H6:H414").Value, 2), "<1", Left(wB.Sheets("Schedule Daily Bank Structure R").Range("H6:H").Value, 2), "=>3")
'Does not seem to be well specified
```

I have constantly the message "Error 13" so , I guess my `SumIfs` is wrong, but I cannot figure out what is,  hope I can still loop different Excel files within it (my wb) I don't know where the problem is coming from. 
It does not work with a simple `SumIf` either.

Comment: i beliave you've mistakenly put the set wb and for each linew twice. anyway, the problem might arise from the range("a:a"). instead you should try it range("a6:a614")

Comment: You can't modify the reference ranges in the sumifs only the criteria by which it is checked.

Comment: Your best choice is going to be load both ranges into an array and cycle through the array that has H6:H414 doing your checks and if it matches sum the corresponding value from the other array.

Comment: Thank you for your replies,  Actually I put H6:H414 because I have cell of fills with text in H5 and H415 so I do not want "confuse" the function left with my conditions with that text. But not sure it really matter, simply  (H:H) might run.
Scott Craner , you mean doing a loop within the new aray I would create..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only glaring issue I see is an inconsistency in ranges; will also shorten up the text using a with statement:

```
With wB.Sheets("Schedule Daily Bank Structure R")
    SumResult2 = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(.Range("A6:A414"), Left(.Range("H6:H414").Value, 2), "<1", Left(.Range("H6:H414").Value, 2), "=>3")
End With
```

A:A versus A4:A414, being the inconsistency.  You are evaluating from H6 down, which does not correlate directly to A6 down when using A:A.

---

If you're still having issues and you think it's the Left(,) portion of your work, I would recommend setting a dimension, such as:

```
Dim rngH as Integer

    With wB.Sheets("Schedule Daily Bank Structure R")
        rngH = Left(.Range("H6:H414").Value, 2)
        SumResult2 = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(.Range("A6:A414"), rngH, "<1", rngH, "=>3")
    End With
```

When you step through the code, you will be able to see if rngH is being picked up correctly.  If it is picked up correctly, then you can check to make sure that your parameters for the range are as expected by VBA.

---

*Edit:*  Giving you a different approach:

```
    Dim rngH, i, j, k As Integer
    With wB.Sheets("Schedule Daily Bank Structure R")
        For i = 6 To 414
            rngH = Left(.Cells(i, "H").Value, 2)
            If rngH > 1 And rngH <= 3 Then 'Value is between 1 and 3; corrected per comments
                k = .Cells(i, "A").Value
            End If
            j = j + k
            K=0
        Next i
        'Output j somewhere
    End With
```

This will, rather than using sumifs function, uses just a loop.

---

*Edt2:*

Let's give you one more change to this, now that we've got a better understanding of where you want to be:

```
Dim rngH, i, j, k, b As Integer
With wB.Sheets("Schedule Daily Bank Structure R")
    For b = 0 to 23
        For i = 6 To 414
            rngH = Left(.Cells(i, "H").Value, 2)
            If rngH = b Then
                k = .Cells(i, "A").Value
            End If
            j = j + k
            K=0
        Next i
        Sheets("Master").Cells(2, b+2).Value = j 'Edit this where you want the output
        j=0
    Next b
End With
```

This would be able to be run for each workbook, reporting data for each hour (no need for a range if you're looking to get operations in a single hour).  Where Sheets("Master") is used, figure out where you want the reporting value to be.

---

**Edit3:**

We're outside of the scope of the question, but will try to give one last bit of help:

```
   For Each fileobj In FolderObj.Files
       Set wB = Workbooks.Open(fileobj.Path)

   e = d

   'Other code to go through the hours
   Sheets("Master").Cells(d+2, b+2).Value = j 'Edit this where you want the output
   'Hopefully that makes sense

   f = 1
   d = e + f

Next fileobj
```

This would give a value that iterates with the fileobj change, which can be directly added to the output cell as the row.  Just make sure to Dim d as Long, e as Long, f as Long.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Cyril , indeed use the With is better , but I still get a mismatch error (error 13)...

Comment: @IlvarNourtan Did you try the recommendation to ensure that the Left(,) is picking up the assumed value?

Comment: @IlvarNourtan also try using ">=3"

Comment: It seems to be picked up correctly since by doing step by step it crash at:
SumResult2 = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(.Range("A6:A414"), rngH, "<1", rngH, "=>3")

Comment: @IlvarNourtan You never declared SumResult2; you have declared SumResult

Comment: oh Yes I know this is because I have other column to sum and decide to only show one to explain better, and I did a typo in the code while I was pasting here, sorry,

Comment: I restarted everything with your idea , I created 2 simples excel files with only column A and H , which I filled until row 10 with number.
And the problem remains the same when I run ..

Comment: @IlvarNourtan See edit.  Went a different route than correcting the sumifs().  A simple loop with if-criteria should provide the desired output.

Comment: @IlvarNourtan In testing, I'm curious about your criteria... is it supposed to be >1 and <=3 ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea of the loop,  No actually this is  1 <rngH<3 
I know the critera I provided totally do not work, but as I was so "upset" I tried with every combination of critera and I left the wrong one ,  but Yes the correct i  <3 and >=1  of course ...

Comment: @IlvarNourtan lol, that is what I was asking; you confirmed my question.  Your code written shows less than 1 and greater than or equal to 3.  I gave both examples in the code I posted (commented out the "correct" version).

Comment: This is not the source of the problem unfortunately..
And for the output of j , As I want it to shift below for every new sheet looped , can I do it something like:   Workbooks("Libro1").Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A1").Value = j.Offset(1, 0)  ?

Comment: @IlvarNourtan  I understand this is not the problem source, but wanted to make sure the corrections I provided were correct.  I would recommend using the loop I provided as the simplest means to circumvent the issue in using SumIfs.

Comment: Yes is seems a very good idea,  it does not display error message when I run it , but nothing appears in my excel file I think is a problem of output , I don't know how to shift the j in the row below once it changes of file ..

Comment: @IlvarNourtan See the edit I made, moving the j out of the if statement, but in doing so I also had to specify that k=0 after j has been updated.  Where there was no output from the previous code, it was because nothing met the criteria, so j and k were always 0.  I don't think I understand what you mean by *shift the j in the row below once it changes of file*.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: I explained all I am trying to do below, hope I am not too long in my explanations. It has been several day I am working in it, not so easy as a VBA novice,  Your loop appears to be the most sensible solution

Comment: @IlvarNourtan Take a look at Edit2.  I have the loop occuring for hours 0 to 23 (b) and goign through your rows (6:414).

Comment: @IlvarNourtan The biggest assumptions are in that output, where b represents the column.  I assumed that row 1 is headers and column 1 was also headers.  You can utilize "b+2" to be columns(0+2)=columns(b), which iterates with each b from 0 to 24.

Comment: Cyril, Thank you very much, you just made my day, I have to commute from work to home (sorry to tell my life), Ill run everything when I reach my house , this triple loops seems very efficient

Comment: But with this lasr code, I will be able to fill only one row, it does not change of row when it changes of file ..

Comment: @IlvarNourtan You would need to tie this to the workbook, as you loop through those in your code.  Not to push you away, but I believe we've moved far beyond the use of Left and SumIfs, which was what the post was about.  It might be worthwhile to post another question about tying your FileObj to a number (possibly counting each book used).  Give me a few to edit my response to include something about that.

Comment: @IlvarNourtan  See my Edit3.  That should resolve that issue.

Comment: Well, I did not understand everything I guess;  e=d right after For Each fileobj In FolderObj.Files
    Set wB = Workbooks.Open(fileobj.Path)

But I will define 24 different variables it might works this way too ,   thanks for everything

Comment: @IlvarNourtan I apologize for not responding to your comment; I appear to have missed it (13 days ago... bad on me).  The e=d is because you are adding and iterating at the end of each loop to get d.  You want d=e+f, and you want e to increase to the last total (d), so before you start iterating again, you make e = d, so that new total = old total + f.

Comment: Absolutely no problem, thank you for your reply. Therefore, for each new files runned through the loop d has to increase by 1 this is the idea? 
As well you put two times the " ForEach ..." it was'nt done on purpose right?

Comment: @IlvarNourtan That is the idea, that you iterate by 1 for each loop.  I corrected the error in my post; you were correct that there should not be 2x For each.

Comment: Oh I got it,  I am a very beginner with VBA and in this kind if programming of general , as one can imagine. Your anwers had been really useful for me. Thank you for all

Answer (score 0):

I am currently here:
I tries it with a extreme simple excel file, and I  get a mismatch error in:
 SumResult2 = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(.Range("A2:A11"), rngH, "=>0", rngH, "<2")

```
Sub refresh_OEdc3333_data_files()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wB As Workbook
Dim SumResult As Double
Dim OutPutRange As Range
Set FileSystemObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Fill it with your own adress
Set FolderObj = FileSystemObj.GetFolder("C:...\")
Set OutPutRange = Workbooks("Libro1").Sheets("Hoja1").Range("D4")

   For Each fileobj In FolderObj.Files
       Set wB = Workbooks.Open(fileobj.Path)

     Dim rngH As Integer

With wB.Sheets("Hoja1")
    rngH = Right(.Range("H2:H11").Value, 2)
    SumResult = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(.Range("A2:A11"), rngH, "=>0", rngH, "<2")
End With



       OutPutRange.Value = SumResult
       Set OutPutRange = OutPutRange.Offset(1, 0)
    wB.Save
wB.Close

Next fileobj
```

End Sub

It do not look that difficult though ... but impossible to get a result

Actually, I have a folder full of excel sheet with the same form and for each of those document I have in column A  certains number of operation, this number is associated with a certain hour, 12:03 appears 1203 in column H.

For example one can have for sheet 1 of the folder:

```
A        H
4242     0032
2342     0034
653      0043
865      0057
53       0154
64       0159
```

And in sheet2 :

```
A       H
54      0002
76      0045
54      0056
43      0058
56      0105
765     0153
43      0157
 .       .
 .       .
 .       .
546     2334
43      2359
```

What I am trying to do is to create a matrix in another worksheet which would be under the form:

```
    H1    H2    H3    H4    H5 ... H24 

1
2
3
4
.
.
.
Total number of file in my folder
```

H1 ...H24 correspond at a time slot, for example H1 : 00:00 to 00:59, H2 01:00 to 01:59 ... etc

1, 2, 3 ... is the number of sheets

This matrix would sum the number of operation (contained in A) for each period of time (each hour) and for each files, hence the matrix ...

```
Sub refresh_OEdc33333_data_files()
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wB As Workbook
Dim SumResult As Double
Dim OutPut As Range
Set FileSystemObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Fill it with your own adress
Set FolderObj = FileSystemObj.GetFolder("C:...\")
Set OutPut = Workbooks("Libro1").Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A1")

   For Each fileobj In FolderObj.Files
       Set wB = Workbooks.Open(fileobj.Path)

   Dim rngH, i, j, k As Integer

With wB.Sheets("Hoja1")
    For i = 2 To 11
        rngH = Left(.Cells(i, "H").Value, 2)
        If rngH < 7 And rngH >= 0 Then
            k = .Cells(i, "A").Value

        End If

     k = 0
   j = j + k

    Next i

      OutPut.Value = j
 Set OutPut = OutPut.Offset(1, 0)

     End With


    wB.Save
wB.Close

Next fileobj
```

End Sub

And my idea is to repeat 24 times the loop you gave me. So far it gave me only 0 .. but I am sure your idea is the good one